# A new guard page for the stack cannot be created

Tags: c#-4.0

We are using C# Application For Developement.

We are using COM component for Rendering and Displaying Image File In ImageViewer.
Sometimes we got Weird System Error As 'A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.'
After this error Application Get Exited.

Is any one have idea why this Error Arise ? As there is no specific case to replicate same error.

Thanks

Comment: Your COM server crashed with this site's name.  A stack overflow exception is always nasty.  If you are 100% sure that it isn't your code that caused it then contact the COM author or vendor for support.

Comment: Is there any way we can catch this exception from Code?

Comment: They would not have given this site its name if this was easy to deal with.  It's not, an SOE is a fatal mishap 99.99% of the time.  It is always a programming bug, you need to find the bug.  With a debugger.

Comment: Did you mange to solve it? It seems, from my investigation, that happens when an unmanaged component tries to put more than 256KB of data in the stack

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was having the same exception but in a different context. I was running a windows service to do some very heavy processment (no COM objects here).

In my case, I found a memory leak in my code that was producing the error "A new guard page for the stack cannot be created." due to out of memory.

I know your question is now 2 years old.. Even though I'm sharing this to help any future reader. VS 2015 has now a nice tool to monitor memory usage during the debug.

-------- Edit ------

Another common scenario for this exception is running out of stack due a recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, Windows virtual memory was not set large enough, or not set to System Management.

Open File Explorer > right click This PC > Properties,

[image: Open System Properties]

Advanced System Settings

[image: Open Avanced System Settings]

Advanced tab > Performance section > Settings

[image: Performance window]

Advanced tab, click Change

[image: Advanced System Performance tab]

Select a drive, and click System Managed, don't forget to click Set.

[image: Page file settings window]

I had VR games crash on me until I remembered that I changed the page file size to a small size. Apparently my system needed more than 20 GB of ram and that caused crashes.

Answer (score -2):

You are using too much heavy processes using visual studio IDE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).