# A new guard page for the stack cannot be created ,EXCEPTION_CODE_STR: c00000fd

Tags: vb.net

I am working vb project in which I am using a media player which is showing videos in a loop. Everything is working fine but after maybe 10 to 12 hours (time is not specific) showing me this dialog box saying close the program or Debug the program (below is the screenshot) but my app is still running.[image]

I created a crash dump file and when I tried to figure out the reason then I found that below is the reason for this error. I used WinDbg to debug the crash dump file. 
[image]

By seeing this I found that maybe this is a memory leak issue but I am not able to figure out from the code that where is the actually exception is occurring. As my app is not throwing any error during the running app but it throws after 10 or 12 hours.

I am new in VB I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

Comment: *"I am not able to figure out from the code"*. Imagine our difficulty then, not even being able to see the code. If there's a stack overflow then that would suggest that you have some direct or indirect recursion. You could run your project in the debugger for a number of hours and then look at the call stack to see whether there is a method or sequence of methods that is called repeatedly. If there is, you then need to determine why and how to prevent it. We can't be any more specific without specific information.

Comment: Perhaps build in some exception handling into your app, then drop the call stack out to a file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780196/a-new-guard-page-for-the-stack-cannot-be-created) post a possible reason could be a memory leak in your code.